# Select Distinct Showing Multiple Values of Same Record

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the code below where I want to see sales for a UPC over a period of time. As you can see, I have Select Distinct to start, but it is still showing multiple entries for the same UPC.

I would like it to show the UPC and then sum up the values for that UPC if there are multiple ones.
Any insight?

I have the code below. 
I have the "Group By" comment taken out, because each time I tried to group by UPC, it game me an error that said "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group."

```
SELECT DISTINCT ir.region, 
                ir.upc, 
                ir.item_long_description, 
                ir.team_name, 
                ir.subteam_name, 
                brand, 
                p.sale_units, 
                p.sale_value 
FROM   prd_sales_cost_summary_v p 
       JOIN item_region_v ir 
         ON p.upc = ir.upc 
            AND p.pos_dept = ir.pos_dept --AND p.store_number = ir.store_number 
WHERE  ir.subteam_name = 'Frozen' 
       AND 
       --prd_idnt BETWEEN 201601 AND 201602 AND 
       prd_idnt = 201601 
       AND 
       --Change the region if needed 
       ir.region = 'RM' 
--GROUP BY 2 
ORDER  BY p.sale_units DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group."

This mean if you put a field on the `SELECT` list you have to put it on the group by.

So

```
 SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, SUM(*)
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY fieldA, fieldB, fieldC
```

Also note your select doesn't have any agreagation function `COUNT()` `SUM()` `AVG()`

Comment: You're definitely right. I had the Sum() on the sale units and values, but it did not carry over. Anyway, used the logic you had and it is working now.